# Custom picklist field not showing in Flow builder

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, lightning-design-system

I am creating flow with a picklist I am creating a new resource and selected the object but in field lookup in new resource window I am unable to find my picklist. I have checked the profile permissions having read and edit.

Comment: Did you check permissions for System Administrator profile? @Sai